# .yml file if condition is not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, yaml, cicd, aws-codepipeline

I am creating CICD for my WordPress project with the help of AWS CodePipeline. I have created Three branches: master, staging, & dev on GitHub, and I need to apply CICD to all three branches. I have created an EC2 instance on AWS where I have created two folders for project-dev & project-staging with subdomains (master is on client AWS account). I have created different CodePipeline's for all branches. As we know code `appspec.yml` which is as below.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - if: branch == 'staging'
      location: stagbr/AfterInstall.sh
      timeout: 1000
      runas: ubuntu
    - if: branch == 'dev'
      location: devbr/AfterInstall.sh
      timeout: 1000
      runas: ubuntu
    - if: branch == 'master'
      location: scripts/AfterInstall.sh
      timeout: 1000
      runas: ubuntu  

permissions:
  - object: /home/ubuntu
    owner: ubuntu
    group: ubuntu
    type:
      - directory
      - file
```

Even though I used the "if" condition, I observe that all the `AfterInstall.sh` files are being executed when I push the code to the dev branch. Additionally, I encounter an error stating that the master project folder cannot be found.

I tried to add the if condition but I am not able to get the branch name there and cant add the if condition.

```
#!/bin/bash
#npm install
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
export HOME="/home/ubuntu/"
cd /home/ubuntu/wordpress/proejctName/
git pull origin dev
nvm use
yarn install
yarn build
```

I tried to access the git branch in `AfterInstall.sh` got below error in CodePipeline

```
Script - AfterInstall.sh
[stderr]fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Please let me know how to handle this situation with correct yml and `AfterInstall.sh` file.